# Как правильно стилизовать input с паролем

Tags: javascript, html, css

При создании input с паролем в форме авторизации на сайте, захотел сделать возможность просмотра своего пароля, путём нажатия на кнопку в виде глаза. Это я сделал, но появилась небольшая проблема. Теперь при вводе большого пароля в input - этот пароль перекрывает кнопку. Как поступить лучше? Из предложений есть вариант сделать просто чекбокс внизу, но это не красиво и не интересно, хочется оставить такую кнопку и решить данную проблемку.

**P.s:** Я даже сделал так чтобы при определённом количестве символов в input переносить эту кнопку  правее, но символы бывают разной ширины, в зависимости от заглавных букв и тд они все равно заходят за границу и никак не посчитать сколько точно нужно символов для сдвига кнопки.

[image: Пароль заходит за границы кнопки просмотра содержимого]

Comment: ну так убери иконку, пускай браузер обрабатывает поле стандартно.

Comment: Приложите [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Задайте фон глазу, тогда текст визуально будет уходить под него. Дополнительно можно накинуть тень для того же цвета что и фон что бы текст плавно скрывался под кнопкой.

Comment: @Ein, как это сделать, если фон (background) и есть эта картинка .svg

Comment: Можно расположить инпут с паролем и глаз в одном блоке со стилем `display:flex`, и тогда они не будут пересекаться

Comment: @ИванЕрмаков если это фон input, то сделать элементом. Если это уже элемент, то задать несколько `background` через запятую. Четвёртый пример из документации: [background | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/background)

Comment: Вы все серьёзно? А добавить `padding-right` для инпута, религия не позволяет?

Answer (score 2):

Как по мне самый лёгкий способ - это просто кнопку расположить справа и задать им бесцветный задний фон

```js
const password = document.querySelector('#password');
const toggleVisibility = document.querySelector('#toggle-visibility');
let state = new Map([
  ['password', 'text'],
  ['text', 'password']
])

toggleVisibility.addEventListener('click', () => {
  password.setAttribute('type', state.get(password.getAttribute('type')))
})
```

```css
:root {
  --border-radius: 8px;
}

body {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

div.password {
  display: flex;
  background-color: gray;
  width: fit-content;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);  
}

input {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius) 0 0 var(--border-radius);
  padding-right: 4px;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none; //Чтобы убрать обводку при фокусе
}

button {
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0 var(--border-radius) var(--border-radius) 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='password'>
  <input id="password" type="password" />
  <button id="toggle-visibility">Eye</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Ещё инпуту задать внутренний отступ справа, чтобы "глаз" не залезал на текст инпута и будет прям рабочий вариант)

Comment: @De.Minov Готово) Вообще мои стили можешь у меня править, без разрешения, если в будущем захочешь - это экслюзивное предложение :)

Comment: Спасибо, но это не правильно)

Comment: @De.Minov Ну пользоваться или нет этим - ваш выбор, моё дело предложить, как говорится)